# How to join 2 tables that have the values represented differently in each table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently have 2 tables `estimate_details` and `delivery_service`.

`estimate_details` has a column called `event` that has events such as: checkout, buildOrder

`delivery_service` has a column called `source` that has events such as: makeBasket, buildPurchase

`checkout` in `estimate_details` is equivalent to `makeBasket` in `delivery_service`, and `buildOrder` is equivalent to `buildPurchase`.

**estimate_details**

| id | event | ... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | checkout | ... |
| 2 | buildOrder | ... |

**delivery_service**

| id | source | date | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | makeBasket | '2022-10-01' | ... |
| 2 | buildPurchase | '2022-10-02' | ... |
| 1 | makeBasket | '2022-10-20' | ... |

I would like to be able to join the tables on the `event` and `source` columns where `checkout` = `makeBasket` and `buildOrder` = `buildPurchase`.

Also if there are multiple records for the specific ID and source in `delivery_service` , choose the latest one.

How would I be able to do this? I cannot `UPDATE` either table to have the same values as the other table.

I still want all the data from `estimate_details`, but would like the latest records from the `delivery_service`.
The Expected output in this situation would be:

| id | event | Date | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | checkout | '2022-10-20' | ... |
| 2 | buildOrder | '2022-10-02' | ... |

Comment: based on sample input data in your question - show example of expected output

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant just added it.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to use a CTE, which is like a subquery but more readable.

So first, in the 'CTE' you will use the delivery_service table to get the max date for each id and source. Then, you will handle the 'text' to manually replace it to make it match that in estimate details

```sql
WITH delivery_service_cte AS (
  SELECT
    id
    , CASE 
       WHEN source = 'makeBasket' THEN 'checkout'
       WHEN source = 'buildPurchase' THEN 'buildOrder'
      END AS source
    , MAX(date) AS date
  FROM
    delivery_service
  GROUP BY
    1, 2
)
SELECT
 ed.* -- select whichever columns you want from here
 , ds.id
 , ds.source
 , ds.date
FROM
  estimate_details ed 
  LEFT JOIN 
  -- or JOIN (you didn't give enough info on what you are trying to achieve in 
  -- the output
  delivery_service_cte ds 
  ON ds.source = ed.event
```